# Using an offset and range inside a loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, offset

I know this will be a stupid simple answer, but it's killing me right now...

```
For Each cell In rng2
    If cell.Offset(0, -13) And cell.Offset(0, -12).Value <> "" Then
        cell.Value = 1
    Else
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
Next cell
```

Where the .offset **and** .offset is, how can i just say

```
If cell.offset(0,12:13)
```

I know that's not it... This one is simple however, getting this piece right will save me so much headache throughout the vba code all over the workbook.

Thanks for helping this rookie in advance!

Comment: Creating a range from offset is possible but, I believe, more difficult than this: `If cell.Offset(0, -13)  <> "" And cell.Offset(0, -12).Value <> "" Then`.  Your expression means: `cell.Offset(0, -13) = True And cell.Offset(0, -12).Value <> ""` which I doubt is what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```vb
For Each cell In rng2
    If Application.CountA(cell.Offset(0, -13).Resize(1, 2)) = 2 Then
        cell.Value = 1
    Else
        cell.Value = 0
    End If
Next cell
```

Comment: Yup, that was the ticket! See I knew it was something stupid simple. I always forget to use some of the application processes. *face palm* Thank you Mr. Williams!

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative using variant array**

You can combine logical assumptions by multiplication (`True * True` corresponding to `-1 * -1 = 1` in case of both reference cells greater`""`) and try the following:

```
'a) assign both offsets to variant 2-dim array
    Dim v: v = rng2.Offset(0, -13).Resize(, 2)
'b) get values
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)     ' check each row
        v(i, 1) = (v(i, 1) > 0) * (v(i, 2) > 0)
    Next i
'c) write values
    rng2.Resize(, 1) = v
```